# Move committed changes from one file into new branch in git

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a feature branch checked out from main with a few commits that edit various files in the codebase. However, I realize that in an upcoming PR, I don't want to incorporate changes to a specific file, say `file.java`. How can I restore `file.java` to its former state (from main) while creating a new branch with the updates to the file for future use?

Comment: You are using the term HEAD incorrectly here, which makes the question somewhat confusing.

Comment: I updated the question to say restore the state of the file from when I checked out from main (so that the file isn't changed in my PR) - thanks for the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us suppose in your feature branch, where you are now, *file.java* has been edited. You want to save those edits, but right now, you would like *file.java* to look the way it did before your feature branch got started. Then you could say:

```
git branch holdmyplace
git restore --source main -- file.java
```

Now *file.java* in your current branch (when you add and commit) is the same as back in `main`, before you checked out and worked on your feature branch. At the same time, you've got this secret branch, `holdmyplace`, whose state of *file.java* is the edited state. Later, you can use the same technique to copy *file.java* from `holdmyplace` while working on some other branch.

Comment: With this implementation, the holdmyplace branch would have the same commit history as the original feature branch. How could I create a branch that only has one commit with just the changes to this specific file?

Comment: I already told you. You'd make the branch (starting at main or wherever makes sense at the time) and say `git restore --source holdmyplace -- file.java`. You could then delete `holdmyplace`; it has served its purpose.

Comment: Please note however that your question here betrays a misunderstanding of Git. Git commits do not contain "changes", nor is a commit selective of files. A commit is a snapshot of the state of _all_ your files.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I realize this isn't the typical use of git, as I typically would have changes separated by commit and not file. However moving the changes in this file is important for my use case at the moment so I wanted a clean way to take care of it in git

Comment: I think the way I gave you is "clean".

Comment: And I do not regard what you're asking to do as non-typical. It's a perfectly reasonable thing to do.